# Why is my python's code's if statement not validation a condition as True and skipping to the Next Line

Tags: python

```
nums=[1,2,3,10]
k=2
d=len(nums)-1
s=sum(nums)/d
for i in nums:
    dif=s-(i/d)
    if dif == k:
        print(True)
print(False)
```

I am expecting the Output to be True and then False
But it is printing only False
At one point dif=2 & k=2 still Idk why it skips the print(True) statement

Comment: You're comparing a floating point value with an integer. Print `dif` on each iteration and you'll see.

Comment: What kind of debug did you do? Put a breakpoint and follow the code and see why what you expect doesn't happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the division operator "/". In python this defaults to floating point division. Due to floating point error you get a small difference making the values you expect to be equal not equal.

I changed your code to the following:

```
nums=[1,2,3,10]
k=2
d=len(nums)-1
s=sum(nums)/d
for i in nums:
    dif = s-(i/d)
    print(dif, k, dif == k)
```

The output is

```
5.0 2 False
4.666666666666666 2 False
4.333333333333333 2 False
1.9999999999999996 2 False
```

As you see for i == 10 you compare the floating point number 1.9999999999999996 to the integer 2.

You can either convert the floating point number to an integer e.g. using rounding, or compare them as floats which is more involved. (E.g. https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)

Comment: Regarding the advice to cast to an integer, note that `int(1.9999999999999996) == 1`

Comment: @Passerby Thank you, I've edited the answer to more properly express my original intent.